# A faithful positive Radon measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally comapct and Hausdorff space. We say a positive Radon Measure on $X$ is faithful if 
$$0\leq f ~~~,~~~\int fd\mu=0\rightarrow f(x)=0 ~~\forall x\in X$$

Q: True or false: If there is a faithful positive Radon measure on $X$ then $X$ has a countable dense subset ?!

Comment: Is $f $ assumed to be continuous? If yes, then every Haar measure is faithful,  even if $G $ is not second countable.

Comment: Radon measures are bounded and the Haar measure on $G$ is bounded if and only if $G$ is compact. Hence compact groups just should be considered.  Now your example works well. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad I could help. But to be honest, I have never seen a definition where being bounded (i.e. finite) was part of the definition of "Radon measure".

Comment: The total variation of a complex Radon measure is finite (section 6 - Real analysis by Rudin).

Comment: Yes, of a **complex** Radon measure. But positive Radon measures need not be finite. Otherwise, there would be no Haar measure on non-compact LCH groups.

Comment: Okay, I see. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Gamma$ be a set of cardinality greater than the continuum. Consider the product measures on $\{0,1\}^\Gamma$ or $[0,1]^\Gamma$. Then they are both faithful even though the underlying compact spaces are non-separable.

Under some extra set-theoretic assumptions, it is even possible to construct a compactification $\alpha \mathbb{N}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ with $\alpha \mathbb{N}\setminus \mathbb{N}$ non-separable having a faithful Radon measure.

Comment: Thanks again for your pay attention, Just, what exactly faithful Radon measure have you considered?

Comment: @AliBagheri, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06972

Comment: It is really remarkable.